# how to get discover tweets of twitter in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, twitter

please give me api name or any document to retrieve Discover tweets of twitter.

right now i am using STTwitter framework
and following method is it right or not?

```
 [_twitter _getDiscoverUniversalWithSuccessBlock:^(NSDictionary *metadata, NSArray *modules) {

   } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

   }]
```